# Signing (in Inno Setup) with SignTool fails with "SignTool Error: Invalid command: /d"

Tags: inno-setup, signtool

I had to replace my C drive and I just set up Inno Setup sign tools again.

My signtool value is:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.19041.0\x64\signtool.exe" $p
```

It was failing so I tried at the command line:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.19041.0\x64\signtool.exe" /d "xxx" /du "https://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk" /f "xxx" /p "xxx" /t "http://timestamp.digicert.com" /v "xxx"
```

And it tells me that:

> SignTool Error: Invalid command: /d

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorted. My Inno definition needed to be:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.19041.0\x64\signtool.exe" sign $p
```

I was missing the `sign` prefix.